# Use Jquery output values inside a PHP code to display an image

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I honestly have no idea how jQuery works but I sure understand some PHP. Here is what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to use what looks like jQuery variables (not sure) - these that look like so `'+...+'`

In between the jQuery code, I want to echo an image in PHP using the get_the_post_thumbnail_url(url_to_postid( 'link')). So I have added my PHP in between the code as shown below. But I need to use these jquery variables that look like `'+...+'` or whatever they are called  inside the PHP. Forgive my ignorance on that.

The code

```
jQuery("#gm"+game+" table").append('<tr> <td class="  column-day">'+item.day+' </td> 
<td class="column-date sorting_1"> '+item.format+' </td><td class="  column-comp"> 
<div class="tleaglnk"><a href="'+item.compurl+'" class="liglink">'+item.compname+'</a></div> </td>
<td class="  column-hometeam"> <div class="tteamlnk"><a href="'+item.hometeamurl+'">'+item.hometeamname+'

<?php echo
'<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-3  h2h-team-intros">
<a class="black hover-none col-sm-12 m0Autos" href="
https://example.com/link/' . sanitize_title('+item.hometeamurl+') . '">
<img class="hmp-club-image" src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url(url_to_postid( '
https://example.com/link/' . sanitize_title('+item.hometeamname+')), 
array('alt'   => '+item.hometeamurl+', 'title' => '+item.hometeamurl+', 'class' => 'my_league_img')) . '">
</a></div>' ?>


</a></div> </td><td class="  column-scoretime"> <div class="tbold tgrey"><a href="'+item.scoretimeurl+'">
'+item.scoretimename+'</a></div> </td>
<td class="  column-awayteam"> <div class="tteamlnk">
<a href="'+item.awayteamurl+'">'+item.awayteamname+'</a></div> </td> </tr>');
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show your output as screenshot?

Comment: PHP executes on the server, before jQuery executes in the DOM. To do this, you would need for jQuery to populate the img tags's src attribute, which would trigger the browser to load them.

Comment: My PHP code disables the jQuery functionality.

Comment: I tried to echo like so `<?php echo ''+item.hometeamname+'';?>` which outputs a 0.